# Opening popup over content on page without opening new window

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web design, html, etc.

I'm trying to open a full size picture from a thumbnail that will open up on the same window over the content of the page.

The code I am using is:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="images/Invitations/Birthday Party/1st
             Birthday Dora.jpg" alt="Thumbnail Image 1" class="img4">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4><a href="images/Invitations/Birthday Party/1st Birthday Dora.jpg" 
              onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow', 'toolbar=no, 
              location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizeable=yes, 
              width=934px, height=960px');return false;
          return false;">Girls Dora 1st Birthday Party Invitation A5</a></h4>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I know this code opens a new window, but as I said, I'm only new and I'm trying to open the link over the content of the page. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Search for greybox or lightbox as these are pretty standard libraries that you can add to your page. Also they do all the work for you :-)

Comment: Hi @Jeff, I've downloaded a lightbox to use so my code is now:
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
       <a class="image" href="images/Invitations/Birthday Party/1st Birthday Dora.jpg" data-lightbox="images/Invitations/Birthday Party/1st Birthday Dora.jpg" data-title="My caption">
         <h4>Girls Dora 1st Birthday Party Invitation A5</h4><img src="images/Thumbnails/Dora Thumbnail.jpg" alt="Thumbnail_placeholder.png"/>
       </a>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>

But this isn't working either... Any ideas???

Comment: Did your read/follow the getting started info that is on the page?

Comment: I did @jeff, All good now. I changed a few things around and it's finally working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt is using JQUERY.

Add an

```
<div id='overlay'>
```

whith your image in it to the page.
add the corresponding code in your Header:

$('#overlay').hide();

on click href  --> $('#overlay').show();

read closer in the Jquery-Documentation!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

Note: the demo works best in full screen, as the pop up image will be full-sized. I'm using two different images here to show the size difference, but if the anchor and img tag images are the same picture, you'll get the effect you're looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    "type": "image"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://lorempixel.com/800/800">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="" />
</a>
```